# Open map app with code

Tags: android

I want to open map app with code and I do like this:

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+43.253392+","+-2.902343+"&daddr="+43.262925+","+2.931504));

```
            startActivity(intent);
```

Like this I have to put the origin address and the destiny address but how can I put in the origin address my actual location to make this automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `saddr` parameter

```
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+43.262925+","+2.931504));
```

Comment: Did you put the value in an int variable and then add it to the string or did you put something like "+-2,9+"?

Comment: Than you, I was putting wrong "-2,9+" in order to "+-2,9+" Thanks a lot.